# need help in understanding Arm processor

Tags: arm

I am a mechanical eng student, I am currently studying about the ARM processor. I just came across a question but I don't understand how they could arrive at these answers. Need help in understanding. Also please help in how to convert from negative decimal to hexadecimal. Thank you.

What is the result of the following calculations performed in ARM? How
are the status flags set? (Write the operands and the result in 32-bit
hexadecimal notation!)

> 1. (–1) + (+1)
> 2. (0) – (+1)
> 3. (2^31 – 1) + (+1)
> 4. (–4) + (+5)

The Answers are :

1. (-1)+(+1):

   ```
   -1: 0xFFFFFFFF 
    1: 0x00000001
   ----------------
    0:  0x00000000
   N=0, Z=1, C=1, V=0
   ```
2. (0)-(+1): subtraction replaced by addition and negation => (0)+(-1)

   ```
    0: 0x00000000 
   -1: 0xFFFFFFFF
   ----------------
    0: 0xFFFFFFFF
   N=1, Z=0, C=0, V=0
   ```
3. (2^31-1)+(+1):

   ```
     :  0x7FFFFFFF
    1:  0x00000001
   ----------------
    0:  0x80000000
   N=1, Z=0, C=0, V=1
   ```
4. (-4)+(+5):

   ```
   -4: 0xFFFFFFFC 
    5: 0x00000005
   ----------------
    1:  0x00000001
   N=0, Z=0, C=1, V=0
   ```

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Can you be very specific about what you don't understand? To convert decimal to negative value, first convert decimal to positive value, invert the bits, add one to the LSB.

Comment: [What the flags mean](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473h/Chdijedg.html), [two's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Do at least _try_...

Answer (score 0):

The way to translate negative binary into hexa is called [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Status flags are:

- N : strictly negative result
- Z : result is zero
- C : [carry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag) : if you consider the numbers as unsigned, the operation produces a [carry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_%28arithmetic%29) on the most significant bit, on ARM, this means that the result should be 2^32 + the actual result stored in the register.
- V : [signed oVerflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overflow_flag). This means that the result of your operation hasn't the sign it should have. For instance, you add two positive integers and you get a negative one.